# Plugin config settings: Newline "\n" returns ^@ control character?

Tags: vimscript, plugin-nerdcommenter

I'm trying to configure the [NERDCommenter plugin](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter) to handle multiline ruby comments (i.e., nested inside `=begin` and `=end`).

The relevant setting is something like this:

```
let g:NERDCustomDelimiters = {
    \ 'ruby': {'left': '# ', 'leftAlt': "=begin\n", 'rightAlt': "\n=end" }
    \ }
```

except this gives me the `^@` control character instead of an actual newline.

Found this in [a primer on vimscript](http://www.softpanorama.org/Editors/Vimorama/vim_scripting.shtml)

> Note that strings can be specified with either double-quotes or single-quotes as delimiters. Double-quoted strings honor special "escape sequences" such as "\n" (for newline), "\t" (for tab), "\u263A" (for Unicode smiley face), or "\" (for the escape character).

and made sure to place the strings inside double quotes. Still no dice. What gives?

Comment: If you double escape the newline (`\\n` instead of `\n`), does it change anything? I had a similar problem, and I remember solving it by putting one or more backslashes in front of the newline character. If a double escape fails, maybe try with 3 or 4 escapes.

Comment: I actually tried that, but it just escapes the first backslash, returning a literal "\n" string.

Answer (score 3):

`^@`, if you look at [`man ascii`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/ascii.7), is the ASCII NUL character. That makes me think this has to do with how newlines are inserted in the replacement string of a `:substitute` command. From [`:h :s%`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3As%25):

```
  <CR>        split line in two at this point
              (Type the <CR> as CTRL-V <Enter>)                  s<CR>
  \r          idem                                               s/\r
  \<CR>       insert a carriage-return (CTRL-M)
              (Type the <CR> as CTRL-V <Enter>)                  s/\<CR>
  \n          insert a <NL> (<NUL> in the file)
              (does NOT break the line)
```

Since `\n` inserts a `<NUL>`, perhaps you should try `\r=end`.

Comment: You know, I was going to mention that I'd tried this, too. Unfortunately, I just get another control character (`^M`).

Comment: @RyanLue and `^M` is the carriage return. Odd. I'll have to experiment a bit.

Comment: @muru Have you  succeeded in the experiments ? Having the similar problem here, doing `:'<,'>s/\n/\n\n/` produces `^@^@` instead of newlines, and joins the lines. Even just `s/\n/\n/` gives `^@`

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy try `s/\n/\r\r/`.

Comment: @muru that does produce a newline after each line, but it also produces two newlines after the very last one.

Comment: @muru `s/\n/\r/`  works properly though, which is absolutely weird and unintuitive, since `\r` is supposed to be carriage return in C-quoted strings, not newline

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy and `s/$/\r/`? See the help quoted above, `\r` and CR actually produce normal newlines in the replacement part of an `s` command.

Comment: @muru both `s/$/\r/` and `s/\n/\r/` work exactly the same: add one extra line after newline. I've read the help, but this still inconsistent. In `s/pattern/replacement/` if I put `\n` instead of `pattern` it is treated as newline; if  I put `\n` into `replacement` part - it's not treated as new line.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy the help is consistent: `\r` and `\n` in the *pattern* are treated as usual, `\r` and `\n` in the *replacement* have different meanings (quoted above).